# SQL Num Rows Param/Boolean Error

Tags: mysql

I have been following these tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUI2JDaNpk0
but for some reason when I enter the correct password I get this error:

> **Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login.php on line 12**

Comment: Please show the code that causes the problem.

Comment: I will leave it to someone else to hassle you for using the deprecated and dangerous mysql_ API.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your mysql_query operation failed. When queries fail they return `false`, and when they succeed they return a record set.  It makes no sense to say `mysql_num_rows(false);` and that's why you're getting this error.